# Maintain state of ipad/iphone application while running next time

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, background, multitasking

Suppose i am running my iphone/ipad application my mistake i pressed home key and again i am running my application it started as usual to i don't want to it started as usual i want to it start from the state where i was before pressing home key.

**In short it should be maintain the state of application while i am running next time.

Answer (score 0):

in the function `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` inside your application delegate .m file, be sure that you don't call the `exit` function.  when the home button is pressed, anything in this function will be ran.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    //do nothing
}
```

Comment: Can you put some sample code or any link for this so that i can understand very well ???

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is default as of iphone 4.1 and ipad 4.2. YOu actually have to specifically stop it if you didn't want it. What version are you building for?

If it is the latest build, then like what binnnyb said, ahve a look in `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillResignActive` for functions that will crash or end your app.

Also `exit();` is not app store safe.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:` in your `NSApplicationDelegate` to save your application state.  You can then reload the saved state at startup.

Comment: The apps state is autosaved and auto-loaded with the latest iOs Build